# When hiding text and then re showing it, it doesn't come back properly, it doesn't allocate room for the text appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So on load of document I hide all my description divs, then when hovering over I want the divs to display the text below, however its not allocating space for the text to be there. It gets stuck underneath my footer. However if I tried the invert aka, show it on start and hide it on hover it works perfectly as intended, making space when it reshows itself.

The main part of my code is here
http://www.hastebin.com/yilinademe.xml

http://gurucraft.co.uk/media.php If you look at the thumbnail lower on the page, when you hover over it, you see the title appear but the paragraph does not appear? Makes no sense. I'm assuming the paragraph is getting stuck under footer or something?

Comment: Please post relevant code in the question itself. Additionally, I think a reproducible example in http://jsfiddle.com would be helpful here.

Comment: seconded. Please give a jsfiddle with all the relevant code in it to be a working minimal example. That way we can even give you the answer in the form of a fixed working example.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans just upvote the comment you agree with, no need to post a 2nd identical comment

Comment: I'd be giving out all my code to make it relevant, its impossible to tell unfortunatly, it has to be some where in the code given as I can get it to work via inverting it, but for obvious reasons I really do not want the inverted version. Its just not re-opening the gap that it should do for some reason. Feel free to suggest what else you might need.

Comment: Is there a reason that you do not have the description divs hidden via CSS before the page loads? As in, `display: none` etc., instead of allocating that to javascript?

Comment: Early X-mas present: http://jsfiddle.net/zv8f3/. OP may want to edit to actually display the error he describes.

Comment: If it at all helps heres what I said below: http://gurucraft.co.uk/media.php If you look at the thumbnail lower on the page, when you hover over it, you see the title appear but the paragraph does not appear? Makes no sense. I'm assuming the paragraph is getting stuck under footer or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".view").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().children(".test").show();
  });
  $(".test").hide();
});
```

**Update :**
After looking at the code at your link I found that the the problem is due to one of the jQuery plugin used (isotope), To fix it use this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".view").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().children(".test").show();
    $('.isotopeWrapper').isotope('reLayout');
  });
  $(".test").hide();
});
```

Comment: maybe OP editted it since you looked or something, but I'm not seeing the code errors you point out in `1)` and `2)`

Comment: and there is a `$(document).ready(...`, though it's completely unnessecary as represented...

Comment: I indeed edited it; that was extra code I had there from testing, but yeah I changed my code. 3) is the only relevant one. Also using next(".test") doesn't find it for some reason. It doesn't show at all. However with my code, the title displays but the rest of the text is not displaying, I am assuming that it is getting stuck behind my footer.

Comment: @user why don't you give [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zv8f3) a couple edits so we can actually see this problem you're describing, then we can try to resolve for you. You're asking us to make quite a few assumptions for you, a few of which have already proved incorrect, and time-consuming.

Comment: http://gurucraft.co.uk/media.php If you look at the thumbnail lower on the page, when you hover over it, you see the title appear but the paragraph does not appear? Makes no sense. I'm assuming the paragraph is getting stuck under footer or something?

Comment: You sir are a genius. I love you.